# Why was the Android Stack Exchange created?

Tags: support, specific-site

I don't understand why Stack Exchange has created a separate network for Android when they already have [android](/questions/tagged/android) tags in all of their programming networks? Is this a beginning of language specific network? Can we expect more specific networks in future like:

- php.stackexchange.com
- java.stackexchange.com
- csharp.stackexchange.com
- etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you read the [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) it doesn't have anything to do with coding:

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android
>   device
>
> then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem
> (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?

In fact it's explicitly excluded:

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)

So, no. I don't expect to see java.stackexchange.com any time soon.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is another example of a "non programming questions" site...

Comment: How about tools for Android development, such as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7455105/897968) which was voted off topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: If you're asking for my opinion about where that should go I'd guess nowhere @FriendFX. I'm not going to claim that I know android.se well but that sort of question is normally off-topic everywhere because the answers will just be a series of links to external sites which will degrade over time, while everyone votes on their favourite link. You _can_ comment and ask the author if they found the answer to their question elsewhere... they might still be able to help you.

Answer (score 12):

The Android site is for end-users, it is not a developer site. Questions about Android programming are off-topic there.

Sites that are proposed on Area 51 that are a full subset of an existing sites are usually not created, but the proposal is closed by SE staff.